# snmpwalk community results to timeout

Tags: linux, snmp

My `snmpwalk` suddenly stopped working, which was working earlier, after restarting the snmp also didn't work out, `snmpwalk -v1 -c` gives me timeout and it's working for other machines as well.

I tried to recreate `snmpconf` with community string and IP address but still didn't get through.

While checking in messages I got like this:

> Oct 19 05:07:34 manilavoice rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 8448 due to rate-limiting" the process id is related to snmpd service

I got a message when I ran `snmpwalk -d 10.30.2.58` like this:

```
[root@manilavoice gopal]# snmpwalk -d 10.30.2.58
No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging

Sending 64 bytes to UDP: [10.30.2.58]:161->[0.0.0.0]
0000: 30 3E 02 01  03 30 11 02  04 53 BF 41  80 02 03 00    0>...0...S.A....
0016: FF E3 04 01  04 02 01 03  04 10 30 0E  04 00 02 01    ..........0.....
0032: 00 02 01 00  04 00 04 00  04 00 30 14  04 00 04 00    ..........0.....
0048: A0 0E 02 04  68 CA 67 C6  02 01 00 02  01 00 30 00    ....h.g.......0.
```

and finally:

```
snmpwalk: Timeout
```

Any comments would be appreciated. Also my firewall and SElinux is OFF.  Moreover same `snmpd.conf` file with one more system works fine in different location.

#### EDIT #1

I tried with this, and got the following results:

```
[root@manilavoice spool]# mount -vvv 10.30.4.20:/volume2/Asterisk_Recordings 
/var/spool/newnfs

mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: no type was given - I'll assume nfs because of the colon
mount: spec:  "10.30.4.20:/volume2/Asterisk_Recordings"
mount: node:  "/var/spool/newnfs"
mount: types: "nfs"
mount: opts:  "(null)"
mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.nfs"
mount: external mount: argv[1] = "10.30.4.20:/volume2/Asterisk_Recordings"
mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/var/spool/newnfs"
mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw"
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Oct 19 14:23:33 2013
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=10.30.4.20,clientaddr=10.30.4.48'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Comment: This Q was cross posted on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465833/snmpwalk-community-results-to-timeout. Told OP to delete the SO one.

Comment: Closing as "problem went away", based on OP's comment: "for SNMP after restarting it got resolved.. other machines I have to restart... now I don't why SNMP stopped working all of sudden, is it due to that NFS... its really wired to understand :( – Gopalakrishnan AN Oct 19 '13 at 23:16"

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on debugging to see what's up:

```
$ snmpwalk -D ALL
```

*excerpt from the man page*

```
Debugging
  -d                    dump input/output packets in hexadecimal
  -D TOKEN[,...]        turn on debugging output for the specified TOKENs
                           (ALL gives extremely verbose debugging output)
```

Comment: [root@manilavoice mibs]# snmpwalk -d 10.30.2.58
No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging

Resending 64 bytes to UDP: [10.30.2.58]:161->[0.0.0.0]
0000: 30 3E 02 01  03 30 11 02  04 3F DE 62  60 02 03 00    0>...0...?.b`...
0016: FF E3 04 01  04 02 01 03  04 10 30 0E  04 00 02 01    ..........0.....
0032: 00 02 01 00  04 00 04 00  04 00 30 14  04 00 04 00    ..........0.....
0048: A0 0E 02 04  71 9F 1D B3  02 01 00 02  01 00 30 00    ....q.........0.

snmpwalk: Timeout

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - please add this to your Q, I can't read it in the comments.

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - are there any messages in /var/log/messages before that log message regarding imuxsock?

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - also can you confirm that there isn't a problem with this system at a lower level. What i mean by this is, is the device able to ping the system and otherwise function just fine on the network?

Comment: ping is fine, no issues with that.. also am facing a strange problem where the NFS mounting also not working, I have a NAS device which I mounted now in the log am getting "Oct 19 11:52:42 voiceDB kernel: nfs: server 10.30.4.20 not responding, still trying" really strange :(

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - usually with issues like this it's an issue at a lower level. Esp. when you tell me that it was working fine and now isn't. I would make sure the networking is not the source of your issue by re-seating the Ethernet cable and also exercising the network more than just pinging. You might want to try dragging some large files down to the box via `wget` or `curl`. This will usually result in networking errors getting exposed.

Comment: I just suspecting whether any UDP ports are blocked in the switch level will that be the reason? because since am able to take SSH access which uses TCP whereas only NFS and SNMP are not working both uses UDP....!

Comment: That sounds plausible. Can you confirm that NFS is actually using UDP and not TCP. v3+ can use both.

Comment: I think its using TCP, because am not using -o udp, so by default it uses TCP

Comment: After restarint my server I tried with the command I mentioned in my above main message...

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - so then the issue isn't related to UDP. I'd still be somewhat suspicious of the network still. Can you drag a file back and forth b/w an NFS share?

Comment: How do you want to drag? by ssh?

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - just `cp` a file to and from.

Comment: ok will do via scp

Comment: Ok I think I got it, the hard disk in the NAS has the issue, because that particular volume am not able to access, when I cd to that volume it stuck

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - that could be the network issue. Try the same thing from another system.

Comment: actually what I did is directly I SSH'ed to NAS device and tried to access the volume where am storing the files, when I use that volume am not able to list out the files, one more volume is there, there I can list out the files, both volume are separate disks.

Comment: For SNMP since its from the machine, I don't think its lower level issue... !

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - OK, so is your issue resolved then?

Comment: for SNMP after restarting it got resolved.. other machines I have to restart... now I don't why SNMP stopped working all of sudden, is it due to that NFS... its really wired to understand :(

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - perhaps the connection to the SNMP server did not get closed out previously and so it could not accept new connections from this one particular host? The NFS server is also this SNMP server? Then if they are, that might be related, but I have a hard time seeing that as the connection.

Comment: yes actually there are three servers connecting to the NAS and these three server stopped for SNMP service as well, whereas some more servers are there which SNMP is working and those servers are not shared with NFS...so my conclusion is because of the NAS failure, SNMP stopped working.

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - OK so it sounds like you've solved your issue.

Comment: yep... thanks for your comments... And is it really related that SNMP and NAS?

Comment: @GopalakrishnanAN - from your description best I can tell it sounds related, but as I said, I have a hard time seeing the connection.